# raise AttributeError(name) after resize an image on python with PIL

Tags: python

I  want to resize an image `2.jpeg` to 28*28 pixel and I'm using the module `PIL` for resizing this picture:

I'm create this class :

```
from PIL import Image

import PIL
import numpy
from resizeimage import resizeimage

import scipy.misc

''' This class is to resize input image to MNIST size (28x28 px) '''


class Resize_img:
    def __init__(self, imageName):
        print 'Image -- ', imageName
        self.resized_image = ''
        # resize img to mnist size [28x28]
        with open(imageName,'r+b') as f:
            with Image.open(f) as image:
                cover = resizeimage.resize_cover(image, [28, 28])
        self.resized_image = 'new ' + imageName
        cover.save(self.resized_image, image.format)
        # transform img to MNIST form
        # image to ndarray 
        PILimg = PIL.Image.open(self.resized_image)

        self.mnist_image_input = scipy.misc.fromimage(PILimg,
                                                      True)  # True => space gray! ----------------------------------------------------
        self.mnist_image_input = (numpy.multiply(self.mnist_image_input,
                                                 1.0 / 255.0) - 1.0) * -1.0  # inverse the image :D  ( white -> dark )


def main():  # To test this Class.
    imageTest = '/home/brm17/Desktop/Myapp/2.jpeg'  # The name of the image to resize

    imageTest = Resize_img(imageTest)
    scipy.misc.imshow(imageTest.mnist_image_input)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


# sudo apt-get install libtiff4-dev libjpeg8-dev zlib1g-dev libfreetype6-dev liblcms2-dev libwebp-dev tcl8.5-dev tk8.5-dev python-tk
```

if i run this script , the terminal print :

```
Image --  /home/brm17/Desktop/Myapp/2.jpeg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Resize_img.py", line 40, in <module>
    main()
  File "Resize_img.py", line 35, in main
    imageTest = Resize_img(imageTest)
  File "Resize_img.py", line 18, in __init__
    with Image.open(f) as image:
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 528, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name)
AttributeError: __exit__
```

what is the problem , and how to resolved this ?

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you are using a `with` statement with an object without an `__exit__` method. Simply don't use the with statement:

```
image = Image.open(f)
cover = ...
```

Comment: the error :  

`
    img = img.resize((new_size[0], new_size[1]), Image.LANCZOS)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'LANCZOS'`

Comment: I think it may depend on your PIL version. Try `pydoc PIL.Image.Image.resize` to see your options.

Answer (score 1):

Yes! 
Changing `with Image.open(f) as image:` to `image = Image.open(f)`.
It fixed.